# Mac java app hangs on start when accessibility enabled

Tags: java, macos, javafx, accessibility, install4j

I have a javafx application which i launch with the help of a .app bundle (created with install4j). The .jar launch perfectly in command line or in eclipse but when i use the .app, it hangs for at least 1 minute (the computer freeze) and finaly finish booting after many other hangs. My app require to be added in Security->Accessibility (assistive device). If the app is not added, it will boot perfectly until it ask for the security clearance. Once i add it, it hangs at the very start even before the splashscreen. Any ideas?

Edit : It works when i launch the javaApplicationStub directly.

Comment: Do you have an auto-update checker running at startup?

Comment: The auto-update from install4j, nope.

Comment: So you add your own launcher on Security & Privacy->Accessibility->Privacy and that causes the problem?

Comment: Yes exactly, if i run the applicationStub or the .jar alone it works.

Comment: So what does your application do with the additional privileges that could cause this issue?

Comment: The java app is loading a .dylib which use accessibility API. But why only the .app does that, on 2 different computers i have tried. Must be something with signing or the plist? Running the .jar in command line works.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already resolved this, this will probably have happened due to Java (FX) bugs with Mac OS 10.14 Mojave: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213793
There were 2 or 3 related bugs and they affected all Java versions up to 11.0.2, which was finally released in February 2019.

Upgrading to 11.0.2 or higher or downgrading to Mac OS 10.13 would probably solve this issue. It is not an install4j issue or related to anything other than the use of Java FX on Mojave.

Comment: Thanks, i had to change the macOS installer in install4j for 'macos folder'. This fixed my issue (thanks to Ingo Kegel from install4j). If i upgrade my java version to 11.0.2, i will try again.